# Is the US House of Representatives legally required to elect a Speaker before House business can begin?

Tags: us-house-of-reps

Suppose that an incoming House of Representatives fails to elect a new Speaker. Is there a way for the incoming Representatives to conduct House business without electing a new Speaker, or are the incoming Representatives doomed by the law until a new Speaker is elected?

For example, the swearing in of new Representatives traditionally does not happen until after a Speaker is elected. Absent a Speaker, can new Representatives be sworn in? If not, is the swearing in of a new Representative-elect necessary before said Representative-elect has all the duties and rights of a Representative?

The Speaker also sets the legislative agenda, forms committees, etc. Without a Speaker, can the House set a legislative agenda, form committees, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constitution says "Each House may determine the Rules of its Proceedings."  Legally speaking, if the House of Representatives can organize itself without electing a speaker and can pass rules that allow it to conduct business despite not having elected a speaker, then any bills it passes can continue to be considered as usual.

The tradition of electing a speaker before swearing in the members is just that (a tradition), so it would be possible to break with tradition and swear the members in without a speaker in place.

The house could establish any other mechanism for setting agendas and forming committees by passing a rule to that effect.

As a practical matter, however, a house that cannot elect a speaker is also unlikely to be able to pass a resolution establishing its rules, since this is a more complex question than the election of a speaker, and it furthermore seems unlikely that such a house would be unable to pass any but the most uncontroversial bills.

It also seems most likely that the easiest way to deal with an inability to elect a speaker would be to reach some sort of compromise on that question and then to proceed with the traditional order of affairs, rather than to try to redesign the parliamentary functioning of the house from the ground up, and history shows that this is in fact what has happened in cases where electing a speaker proved difficult.

Comment: I suspect this is a correct interpretation of the Rules of Proceedings Clause, but is there any law supporting it?

Comment: Makes sense to me. I read through Articles I and VI of the Constitution and could not find any language suggesting a penalty for not electing a Speaker.

Comment: There is precedent for the House passing a resolution before the Speaker is elected. [Hind's Precedents](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GPO-HPREC-HINDS-V1/pdf/GPO-HPREC-HINDS-V1.pdf), Section 221, page 138. This was specifically to allow the election of the Speaker with a plurality vote instead of a majority vote.

Comment: Of course, since the likely winner of a plurality election would be Hakeem Jefferies there is no chance that a plurality resolution would be passed.

Comment: @bdb484 any law other than the Rules of Proceedings clause, you mean?  What did you have in mind?  A statute?  A court case in which a court declined to intervene because of the Rules of Proceedings clause?  There is a statute that specifies that the speaker administers oaths to the representatives, but it is unenforceable because of the Rules of Proceedings clause.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the possibility of case law. I believe there's been a fair amount of litigation on the Rules of Proceedings clause; perhaps some of it would indirectly address this issue.